# How to efficiently calculate the number of overlaps between a set of ranges?

Tags: r, data.table, range, overlap

Suppose I have a set of ranges by row:

| lower | upper |
| --- | --- |
| -10.4443200 | -8.695751 |
| -10.5356594 | -7.372029 |
| -3.9635740 | -2.661712 |
| -2.7043889 | -1.051237 |
| 0.8921994 | 2.525341 |
| 0.8495998 | 2.982567 |
| 0.9639315 | 3.149708 |
| 1.2656724 | 3.362623 |
| 2.8932368 | 5.332422 |
| 4.6476099 | 5.489882 |

What is an efficient way to count the number of pairs of ranges that overlap with one another?

One naive way is, but this is slow for millions of comparisons due to the loop. Perhaps a vectorised way using `foverlaps` would be ideal.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
setkey(a, lower, upper)

for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
        foverlaps(a[i,], a[j,])
    }
}
```

```
data=structure(list(lower = c(-10.4443200112593, -10.5356593568179,
-3.96357398513697, -2.70438891891616, 0.892199380698278, 0.849599807772024,
0.963931532617852, 1.2656723800301, 2.89323680524585, 4.64760986325676
), upper = c(-8.69575093847071, -7.37202901360451, -2.66171192367237,
-1.05123670198647, 2.5253413373515, 2.98256679223578, 3.14970844448057,
3.3626226637927, 5.33242229071662, 5.48988156249026)), row.names = c(NA,
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You only need to count them? Not flag them or display them?

Comment: When you say efficient does it mean that you have one solution but it is too slow? Maybe we could help improving your solution instead of developing one for you

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? What sample size is proving inefficient?

Comment: @Sotos yep, just counting is necesarry, i.e. x out of y of all pairwise comparisons overlap

Comment: @llrs well I don't have a solution yet, I cant think of anything other than a very naive and slow loop which would likely be much too slow given I have millions of comparisons to make.

Comment: Would something like this work for you? `sum(sapply(seq(nrow(data)), \(i)sum(i < (1:nrow(data)) & data$lower[i] <= data$upper & data$upper[i] >= data$lower)))`. Ahh...maybe not cause the time complexity is still O(N^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient algorithm would be to sort the combined vector of lower and upper bounds, then for each interval add the number of intervals already open when the interval starts to the number of intervals that start while the interval is open. As a function using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

noverlaps2 <- function(dt) {
  n <- nrow(dt)
  dt[
    ,N := data.table(
      val = unlist(dt),
      i = rep(c(1L, -1L), each = n),
      j = rep(1:0, each = n)
    )[
      order(val), `:=`(N1 = cumsum(i), N2 = cumsum(j))
    ][,N1[1:n] - N2[1:n] + N2[(n + 1):.N] - 1L]
  ]
}
```

Test on the example data:

```
noverlaps2(setDT(data))[]
#>           lower     upper N
#>  1: -10.5356594 -7.372029 1
#>  2: -10.4443200 -8.695751 1
#>  3:  -3.9635740 -2.661712 1
#>  4:  -2.7043889 -1.051237 1
#>  5:   0.8495998  2.982567 4
#>  6:   0.8921994  2.525341 3
#>  7:   0.9639315  3.149708 4
#>  8:   1.2656724  3.362623 4
#>  9:   2.8932368  5.332422 4
#> 10:   4.6476099  5.489882 1
```

Compare timings against @Wimpel's `foverlaps` solution (as a function):

```
noverlaps1 <- function(dt) {
  setkey(dt, lower, upper)
  foverlaps(dt, dt)[, .(N = .N - 1), .(lower, upper)]
}
```

Larger example dataset, with 10K rows:

```
data <- data.table(lower = cumsum(rexp(1e4)))
data[,upper := lower + rexp(.N, 0.1)]
```

Timings:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Wimpel = noverlaps1(dt),
  jblood94 = noverlaps2(dt),
  check = "equal",
  setup = {dt <- copy(data)}
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr     min        lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#>    Wimpel 88.4604 140.10715 223.3559 168.1201 244.86430 828.5056   100
#>  jblood94 14.1549  20.38995  42.8457  26.4350  51.31825 387.5831   100
```

Also note that the performance of `noverlaps2` is not affected when the segments tend to overlap with more segments, while `foverlaps` becomes much slower:

```
data <- data.table(lower = cumsum(rexp(1e4)))
data[,upper := lower + rexp(.N, 0.01)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Wimpel = noverlaps1(dt),
  jblood94 = noverlaps2(dt),
  check = "equal",
  setup = {dt <- copy(data)}
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#>    Wimpel 1000.1568 1200.95605 1411.75152 1353.3996 1555.8535 2252.2487   100
#>  jblood94   12.4723   25.99595   50.43143   43.7304   69.1171  157.1523   100
```

A final note: `noverlaps1` will reorder the data if it is not already ordered by `lower`, whereas `noverlaps2` updates the `data.table` in-place without reordering.

Answer (score 5):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
setkey(mydata, lower, upper)
# !! use .N - 1 because each row overlaps with itself !!
foverlaps(mydata, mydata)[, .N - 1, by = .(lower, upper)]
#          lower     upper N
# 1: -10.4443200 -8.695751 1
# 2: -10.5356594 -7.372029 1
# 3:  -2.7043889 -1.051237 1
# 4:  -3.9635740 -2.661712 1
# 5:   0.8921994  2.525341 3
# 6:   0.9639315  3.149708 4
# 7:   1.2656724  3.362623 4
# 8:   2.8932368  5.332422 4
# 9:   0.8495998  2.982567 4
#10:   4.6476099  5.489882 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [@Mikael Jagan's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76588762/12158757), using `outer` here

```
with(
    data,
    rowSums(outer(lower, upper, `<=`) & outer(upper, lower, `>=`)) - 1
)
```

or a trick of `pmin` with one single `outer`

```
with(
    data,
    rowSums(pmin(m <- outer(lower, upper, `<=`), t(m))) - 1
)
```

which gives

```
1 1 1 1 3 4 4 4 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The intervals `[ai,bi]` and `[aj,bj]` intersect if and only if `ai <= bj` and `bi >= aj`.  So in base R one could do something like:

```r
n <- nrow(data)
a <- data$lower
b <- data$upper
rowSums(a <= matrix(b, n, n, byrow = TRUE) &
        b >= matrix(a, n, n, byrow = TRUE)) - 1
## [1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 4 4 4 1
```

avoiding an R level loop but at the cost of an `O(n*n)` allocation.  That is prohibitive for large enough `n`, obviously.  Thankfully, packages exist ...